# SSD 870 QVO 2TB full after 1TB on Manjaro?

Tags: ssd, manjaro

While doing a backup I got a message saying the disk is full. However, when I inspect disk usage I see only ~half of the disk is full. What gives?

It's the sdb disk with the largest partition mapped to /data:

fdisk -l /dev/sdb

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 1,82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 870 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: XXXX

Device          Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1          34      32767      32734   16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdb2       32768 3700180991 3700148224  1,7T Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb3  3700180992 3907028991  206848000 98,6G Linux filesystem
```

df

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb3        97G   59G   34G  64% /backup
/dev/sda2        95M   26M   70M  27% /boot/efi
/dev/sdb2       1,8T  796G  969G  46% /data
```

inodes weren't an issue when I watched before. I did a clean up after that and this is the inodes now.

```
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sdb2        1,1G  816K  1,1G    1% /data
```

I'm wondering if I need to update the SSD driver. At first glance, that doesn't look straightforward though.

These commands tell me there are no updates available for Samsung SSD:

```
fwupdmgr get-updates
fwupdmgr refresh
fwupdmgr update
```

I'm looking into Samsung Magician now..

Edit: so I kicked out all .BridgeCache directories and pruned an insane Git repo of 70GB. After that I pushed the drive one more time over 1TB up to 1010GB with `dd if=/dev/zero of=/data/baloney`.

I'm not confident this issue won't pop up later but I'm happy the drive isn't hard locked to 1TB for some wonky reason or hardware fraud.

Comment: Is there a prior backup hidden by the Backup App?   Lenovo used  to do that with prior backups.

Comment: No, it's not a Lenovo and backing up in my case just means copying files manually from disk to disk atm as I'm still sorting things out. When I'm happy with the structure I want to use rsync.

Comment: I know that, but check for hidden files / folders

Comment: I checked hidden files and dirs starting with a dot, deleted some but nowhere near 1,1TB. I cleared about 100 GB. du -ah is supposed to count hidden files and reports only 750GB is in use.

Comment: Check `df -i` to see if you're out of inodes

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 inodes are not the issue. I updated the question.

Comment: how are you backing it up?

Comment: @GauravJoseph with Thunar filemanager drag and drop, when the issue presented itself.

Comment: What is Microsoft Basic Data exactly? NTFS, EXFAT, FAT32 etc...

Comment: @GauravJoseph NTFS, it's mounted with NTFS-3G. It's a data drive in a dual boot setup and it works, data is accessible from both OS'es. The only issue I had was with Docker container issues regarding permissions. For those projects, I just moved the code to an ext4 fs.